# topological vector space over locally compact field

Tags: locally-compact-groups

Let $K$ be a nondiscrete locally compact topological field, and $V$ be a finite dimensional topological vector space over $K$ and $\{ v_1, \cdots ,v_n\}$ be a base of $V$.

$\varphi : K^n \rightarrow V$ is  a linear map
$$
\varphi(x_1, \cdots , x_n) = \sum_i x_iv_i .
$$
Then, I want to show that $\varphi$ is an open map. (This is a Theorem 3 on page 5 in *Basic Number Thory*)

Comment: It may fail for "nondiscrete topological field" such as $\mathbb Q$ with the usual metric.  So "locally compact" in your title may be important.

Comment: First try the case $K = \mathbb R$ with its usual metric.